# can I show the value but send the key of an object in a select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

So basically I have an v-for which iterates an array of objects called roles like this:

```
[
   {1 : "Gamer casual"}
   {2 : "Gamer amateur"}
   {3 : "Gamer pro"}
   {4 : "Gamer coach"}
]
```

what I want is to show what it comes from the database (the text), for example "gamer casual", but if they want to change it, send the key of the choice to the database. I guess it must be something simple and everything I have checked is not working but I cannot get to see what I am doing wrong, this is my select:

```
<select v-model="profile.role" class="inputEdit inputSelect">
   <option
       v-for="(key, value, index) in roles"
      :value="profile.role"
      :key="index"
      >{{ value }}</option>
</select>
```

where my object profile it is like this one:

```
profile: {
  name: this.profile_info.name,
  surname_1: this.profile_info.surname_1,
  nick: this.profile_info.nick,
  role: this.profile_info.description,
  about: this.profile_info.about,
}

so what I need is to send the number of the selected value in the select but I do not get to show the value and link the key to profile.role I have also tried using v-bind:value instead just :value with same result. Any hint would be much apreciated! Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case the value is an element from the v-for (example: `rol` and `index` on value)

```js
var roles = [
   {1 : "Gamer casual"},
   {2 : "Gamer amateur"},
   {3 : "Gamer pro"},
   {4 : "Gamer coach"},
]

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    profile: {
      role:''
    },
    roles: roles
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    {{profile}}
    <select v-model="profile.role" class="inputEdit inputSelect">
          <option :value="index+1" v-for="(rol, index) in roles">{{rol}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I see the value is set to rol.role and I want to always show what it comes from the database which it will be profile.role, is this possible?

Comment: Segun veo hablas español, creo que entendi mal tu pregunta ... una consulta roles es un array o un objeto?
Y si quieres guardar en profile.roles, esta bien ponerlo en el v-model pero no en el value

Comment: roles es un array de objetos, acabo de editar la pregunta, veo que estaba mal, perdon

Comment: como esta actualmente lo puedes obtener poniendo en `:value="index+1"`
Pero te recomendaria cambiar el formato del array,
`var roles = [
   {id: '1', value: "Gamer casual"},
   {id: '2', value: "Gamer amateur"},
   {id: '3', value: "Gamer pro"},
   {id: '4', value: "Gamer coach"}
]`

Comment: Viene con ese formato directamente de base de datos

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, con el comentario anterior, puedes verlo en funcionamiento ... el inconveniente seria si el id no es secuencial

Comment: el id siempre va a ser secuencial, es una tabla maestra con solo esos datos, El problema es que al poner :value="key" no me pinta por defecto el valor que viene de la base de datos...

Comment: not sorting the problem yet; first render the select does not show what it comes from DB

Answer (score 2):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    roles: {
       "1" : "Gamer casual",
       "2" : "Gamer amateur",
       "3" : "Gamer pro",
       "4" : "Gamer coach"
    },
    profile: {
      role: -1
      // ... other keys
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    updateToDatabase (event) {
      console.log('send this updated key to database : ' + event.target.value)
      // ... api call
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <div style="background: yellow;">
    selected key: {{ profile.role }}
  </div> 

  <select 
    v-model="profile.role"
    @change="updateToDatabase"
  >
   <option
    v-for="(value, key, index) in roles"
    :value="key"
    :key="index"
   >
    {{ value }}
   </option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: not sorting the problem yet; first render the select does not show what it comes from DB

Answer (score 0):

```js
// let's assume this comes from your db.
var profile_info = {
    // ... other data
    description: 'Gamer amateur'
};
var roles = {
    1: "Gamer casual",
    2: "Gamer amateur",
    3: "Gamer pro",
    4: "Gamer coach"
};
var initialRoleId = Number(Object.keys(roles).filter((key) => roles[key] === profile_info.description)[0]);

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        profile: {
            //other data
            role: profile_info.description
        },
        roles: roles,
        roleId: initialRoleId
    },
    methods: {
        updateRole: function(e) {
            this.profile.role = this.roles[this.roleId];
            console.log('send this to the db: ' + this.roleId);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div>Selected Role: {{ profile.role }}</div>
    <br><br>
    <select v-model="roleId" @change='updateRole' class="inputEdit inputSelect">
        <option v-for="(role, id, index) in roles"
                :value="id"
                :key="index"
                :selected="id==this.roleId ? true : false"
        >{{ role }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanls for replying! But it is not clear to me where is initialRoleId  suppoused to be set in data?

Comment: InitialRoleId will allow you to display the role once it is set. For example, when a user revisits the page, for reviewing or editing. Then the page can retrieve the data from db and display the role.